# What are the causes of a 416 Error?

Tags: apache

One of my visitors from my website informed me that every so often (quite rarely actually), when trying to visit my website, he gets a **416 Error: Requested Range Not Satisfiable**

I've never heard of such an error, and don't see anything strange anywhere on my apache logs.

What can cause such an error?

My website is a wordpress blog, running on apache, centos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been covered on Stack Overflow: [416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891431/416-requested-range-not-satisfiable)

Check the error log for the 416 error. [I know you said you checked. It should be there unless you are including a resource from another server.] That should tell you what file. Then make sure it is getting cached correctly [or not cached at all].

**UPDATE:**

What you can do with APC, is disable caching of certain files by using the `apc.filters` setting in your `php.ini` [or `apc.inc` or however you are including the apc config.] If you can figure out which file[s] are throwing the 416 error, you can start by configuring APC to not cache them. Sounds like a reasonable start to me.

Actually, come to think of it, if you can find the file throwing the error, you can use APC to, 1, see if it is cached; and 2, check on the file size that APC thinks it is; then 3, check the actual size on disk. Check out this link: devzone.zend.com/article/12618 [the official APC docs kinda suck]

Comment: The question you linked had the server running APC. Coincidentally, my server also has APC installed. Can this be a cause?

Comment: what you can do with APC, is disable caching of certyain files by using the apc.filters setting in your php.ini [or apc.inc or however you are including the apc config] If you can figure out which file[s] are throwing the 416 error, you can start by configuring APC to not cache them. Sounds like a reasonable start to me.

Comment: AAAACtually, come to think of it, if you can find the file throwing the error, you can use APC to 1. see if it is cached &  2. check on the file size that APC thinks it is then  3. check the actual size on disk. Check out this link: http://devzone.zend.com/article/12618 [the official APC docs kinda suck]

Answer (score 4):

That error means that some client sends a request to your server which specifies a range of bytes which is not serveable due to some reason.

This can happen with something like this example:

- You have an image with physical size 1000 bytes
- Your Server specifies the wrong content length e.g. 1500
- The client sends a request to get 0 - 1500 bytes from your server
- Your server sends a 416 because the image has only 1000bytes

Comment: Confirmed, when modifying a file while a request is served can lead to 416 errors.

Answer (score 2):

**416 - Requested Range Not Satisfiable**
A 416 status code indicates that the server was unable to fulfill the request. This may be, for example, because the client asked for the 800th-900th bytes of a document, but the document was only 200 bytes long.

What causes this error in your case is hard to tell. I would start with the Apache `error.log` and scan for 416. This way you might be able to narrow it down further to what page was called and go from there.

Comment: 416 doesn't show up on error log.